# listboxes in html, javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdMAF/38/) which does what I want. However, I wanted the boxes to be inline and buttons as arrows.

So I modified above fiddle into this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40awnzhw/).

1) However, this is not working. Can someone please help with what am I doing wrong ? I am not able to move elements from left to right and vice versa.

2) I also want the width and height of my Select boxes as fixed with no scroll bar initially. For e.g. say 6 options. However, if the number of options increases (for e.g. it becomes 10), a scroll bar should automatically appear. Can someone point me to some tutorial which shows this ?

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="bloc">
    <select id="list1" multiple="multiple" rows=2>
        <option value=1>Option 1</option>
        <option value=2>Option 2</option>
        <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        <option value=4>Option 4</option>
        <option value=5>Option 5</option>
        <option value=6>Option 6</option>
    </select>
   </div>
 <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <input id="button1" type="button" value=">>" />
    <br/>
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="<<" />
 </div>
<div class="bloc">
    <select id="list2" multiple="multiple" rows=2>        
    </select>   
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
        });
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
 .bloc { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; border:solid grey 1px; width:100px;}
```

Comment: You are missing jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: @Arvind: The first JSFiddle has no jquery in it.. still its working!

Comment: have a closer look into console while running the OP modified fiddle. it gives undefined error for `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing jQuery in your fiddle. Below your working example <strike>with just one change i.e. added jquery import.</strike>

**Edited**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function() {
      $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
    });
  });

  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function() {
      $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.bloc {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*border: solid grey 1px;*/
  /*width: 100px;*/
  height: 80px;
}
.bloc select {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bloc">
  <select id="list1" multiple="multiple">
    <option value=1>Option 1</option>
    <option value=2>Option 2</option>
    <option value=3>Option 3</option>
    <option value=4>Option 4</option>
    <option value=5>Option 5</option>
    <option value=6>Option 6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="bloc">
  <input id="button1" type="button" value=">>" />
  <br/>
  <input id="button2" type="button" value="<<" />
</div>
<div class="bloc">
  <select id="list2" multiple="multiple">
  </select>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I am new to JFiddle and Javascript... did not see that the original JFiddle had jquery imported... could you please help with the ListBox width question as well..